# What is a good hardware setup for using Python across multiple users

Tags: python

This question is likely somewhat naive.  I know I (and my colleagues) can install and use Python on local machines. But is that really a best practice?  I have no idea.

Is there value in setting up a Python "server"?  A box on the network where we develop our data science related Python code.  If so, what are the hardware requirements for such a box?  Do I need to be concerned about any specific packages or conflicts between projects?

Comment: I think that it is impossible to answer this question as it's stated. You may have a better chance of getting a reasonable answer, if you will provide more details about your project(s), goals, specific packages, users (including their number) and requirements for the setup. Keep in mind that, in addition to _local machines_ and _local servers_, you have various **cloud** options, such as _Amazon Web Services (AWS)_.

Comment: This question is not really Data Science related, as it stands now.  Maybe you can elaborate and make the connection clearer?  Otherwise, you may want to move it to Programmers Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is installing Python locally a good practice?**  Yes, if you are going to develop in Python, it is always a good idea to have a local environment where you can break things safely.

**Is there value in setting up a Python "server"?**  Yes, but before doing so, be sure to be able to share your code with your colleagues using a [version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control).  My reasoning would be that, before you move things to a server, you can move a great deal forward by being able to test several different versions in the local environment mentioned above.  Examples of VCS are [git](http://git-scm.com), [svn](https://subversion.apache.org), and for the deep nerds, [darcs](http://darcs.net).

Furthermore, a "Python server" where you can deploy your software once it is integrated into a releasable version is something usually called "[staging server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staging_site)".  There is a whole philosophy in software engineering — [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) — that advocates staging whatever you have in VCS daily or even on each change.  In the end, this means that some automated program, running on the staging server, checks out your code, sees that it compiles, runs all defined tests and maybe outputs a package with a version number.  Examples of such programs are [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org), [Buildbot](http://buildbot.net) (this one is Python-specific), and [Travis](https://travis-ci.org/recent) (for cloud-hosted projects).

**What are the hardware requirements for such a box?** None, as far as I can tell.  Whenever it runs out of disk space, you will have to clean up.  Having more CPU speed and memory will make concurrent builds easier, but there is no real minimum.

**Do I need to be concerned about any specific packages or conflicts between projects?**  Yes, this has been identified as a problem, not only in Python, but in many other systems (see [Dependency hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)).  The established practice is to keep projects isolated from each other as far as their dependencies are concerned.  This means, avoid installing dependencies on the system Python interpreter, even locally; always define a [virtual environment](http://virtualenv.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and install dependencies there.  Many of the aforementioned CI servers will do that for you anyway.

Comment: Answered here, but as you can see, there is nothing Data Science specific about the answer.  Hope it helps, anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  Which section of Stack Exchange is the correct one for discussing these issues?  I understand that they are only tangentially related to the topic of Data Science.

Comment: I would move or re-post the question on http://programmers.stackexchange.com . Stack Overflow is for code that is not running as expected, while Programmers SE is for the design stage.  Make it clear you ask for advice on the setup for your team, and not on the setup of Python alone! Otherwise they might suggest to move the question to http://serverfault.com or something ...